How to get the user-input value from a HTML text field
I am learning JS and trying to make a simple calculator on my own with 1 weeks lessons to test myself but I got stuck at getting the user-input values from my HTML text fields,
below is my html:
    <div class="container">
        <input id="first-number" type="number" placeholder="first number">
        <input id="second-number" type="number" placeholder="second number">
        <br /><br />
        <button id="multiplication" onclick="multiply()">Mutliply</button>
        <button id="addition" onclick="addition()">Addition</button>
        <button id="subtraction" onclick="subtraction()">Subtraction</button>
        <button id="divison" onclick="division()">Divison</button>
        <br /><br />
        Your answer is <b><span id="final-answer"></span></b>
    </div>

and below is my JS code:
let firstNumber = document.getElementById("first-number").value;
let secondNumber = document.getElementById("second-number").value;

function multiply() {
    finalAnswser = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    document.getElementById("final-answer").innerHTML = finalAnswser;
    console.log(firstNumber);
};

I am only working on getting the first function correct, since as per my understanding the rest will follow teh same pattern except differnt operators..
PS: I haven't learn the.value porperty as of yet but I Google and came to this solution but even this not working for me, any help is highly appreciate
EDIT: So now I know I was declaring the firstNumber and secondNumber outside of my function before the button actions, and I have also updated my JS code to the following:


function multiply() {
    let firstNumber = document.getElementById("first-number").value;
    let secondNumber = document.getElementById("second-number").value;
    finalAnswser = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    document.getElementById("final-answer").innerHTML = finalAnswser;
    console.log(firstNumber);
};

function addition() {
    let firstNumber = document.getElementById("first-number").value;
    let secondNumber = document.getElementById("second-number").value;
    finalAnswser = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    document.getElementById("final-answer").innerHTML = finalAnswser;
    console.log(firstNumber);
};

function subtraction() {
    let firstNumber = document.getElementById("first-number").value;
    let secondNumber = document.getElementById("second-number").value;
    finalAnswser = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    document.getElementById("final-answer").innerHTML = finalAnswser;
    console.log(firstNumber);
};

function division() {
    let firstNumber = document.getElementById("first-number").value;
    let secondNumber = document.getElementById("second-number").value;
    finalAnswser = firstNumber / secondNumber;
    document.getElementById("final-answer").innerHTML = finalAnswser;
    console.log(firstNumber);
};



and the multiply, division and subtraction are working perfectly but the addition function is adding 2 string instead of numbers.
2nd EDIT:
Alright,so I converted my firstNumber and secondNumber to number using Number() and it worked like a charm :) below is the declaration that I replaced inside all my functions:


    let firstNumber = Number(document.getElementById("first-number").value);
    let secondNumber = Number(document.getElementById("second-number").value);




values of firstNumber and secondNumber should be obtained inside your multiply function. Otherwise you will get those values only once on page load and also the value of those inputs are considered strings. You need to convert them to number before calculating your result. And third issue. Your function is called multiply but you are just summing the 2 numbers rather than multiplying them which is wrong

Does this answer your question? How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?

@JonathanStellwag They already know to use .value. The problem is that they don't know where in their code to put that. I don't think your proposed duplicate answers that.

Perfect, declaring the firstNumber and secondNumber inside the function worked, thanks so much man and I do get it now why the values were not updating on user-input. So all my functions are working except the + (addition), the addition is adding 2 strings instead of numbers (for eg. 5 + 10 = 510) and I have no clue why

You need to make sure the values are evaluating as numbers and not strings. Look up how to parse an input into a number, there is a lot of info out there on how to do that.

Since you say you are learning JS you will want to learn how to attach event handlers instead of using onclick="function"

To get user input from an HTML text field, you can use JavaScript. Here's a simple example of how to do it:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>User Input Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<label for="userInput">Enter your name:</label>
<input type="text" id="userInput" name="userInput">
<button onclick="getUserInput()">Submit</button>

<script>
function getUserInput() {
// Get the value from the input field
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    
// Do something with the user input
console.log("User input:", userInput);
// You can perform any action with the user input here, such as validation, processing, etc.
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

In this example:
• We have an  element with the id attribute set to "userInput".
• We have a  element with an onclick attribute set to call a JavaScript function named getUserInput() when clicked.
• Inside the getUserInput() function, we use document.getElementById("userInput").value to get the value entered by the user in the text field.
• We then log the user input to the console, but you can perform any desired action with it within the function.
